# Load script on frontend from widget plugin

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, widgets

I need a bit of help for a plugin I'm writing. I need to load a custom stylesheet and a custom script that are needed on the frontend only. Usually I use the `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` with the `get_template_directory_uri()` but these scripts are inside the plugin folder and the javascript one needs that swiper.js is loaded and available. On the backend this will cause an error because swiper is not loaded for the backend. How I can fix this and enqueue correctly the scripts?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct(
      'i-widget',
      'I feed',
      array(
        'description' => ''
      )
    );
    add_action( 'widgets_init', array($this, 'init') );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'init' ) );
  }

  public function init()
  {
    register_sidebar(
      array(
        'name'        =>  'I feed',
        'id'          =>  'i-feed',
        'description' =>  'I feed widget',
      )
    );
    register_widget( 'IFeedWidget' );

    wp_enqueue_style('i-widget', plugins_url( 'i-widget.min.css' , __FILE__), array(), null);
    wp_enqueue_script('i-widget', plugins_url( 'i-widget.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery, swiper'), null);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general to load css or js into admin you need to use `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook, so it can be like this in functional style:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function( $hook_suffix ){
    wp_enqueue_style('i-widget', plugins_url( 'i-widget.min.css' , __FILE__), array(), null);
    wp_enqueue_script('swiper', plugins_url( 'swiper.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), null);
}, 99 );
    wp_enqueue_script('i-widget', plugins_url( 'i-widget.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery', 'swiper'), null);
}, 99 );
```

See more at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/

Also in terms of architecture it's better to split up `init` method of your class in parts extracting  enqueue scripts\styles into separate method.

```
public function initScripts(){
   wp_enqueue_style('i-widget', plugins_url( 'i-widget.min.css' , __FILE__), array(), null);
   wp_enqueue_script('swiper', plugins_url( 'swiper.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), null);
   wp_enqueue_script('i-widget', plugins_url( 'i-widget.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery', 'swiper'), null);
}
```

So that in constructor you can hook to it via `add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'initScripts']);` and for frontend `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',[$this, 'initScripts']);`

And when you specify js\css dependencies you provide an array of strings like `array('jquery','swiper')`or `['jquery', 'swiper']`

This one will not work correctly`array('jquery, swiper')`.

Don't forget to put `swiper.min.js` in your plugin's directory or provide proper path to it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I need only to enqueue the scripts on the front-end. I know about admin scripts, but this is not the case. The widgets working fine, the only thing is that I wasn't know about the arryay of dependencies that needs to be separate and not in the same quote for each script. thanks for the help. PS: the widget is now working fine, the only problem is with a single hosting provider (tophost) that will not make it work and I don't understand why (I've tested It on various hosts and works fine)!!